# Ionic google services not found

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic 4 project that makes use of the google maps APIand their development tools. I would like to build the peoject now for android release i ran the command

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

But then i get the following error message

```
* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
 > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
```

I have downloaded the google-services.Json from firebase but I am unsure where i should place it and what files i need to edit. If you want the ciontents of a certain file let me know and ill put it here. Thank you for any help

Comment: Which plugin are you using for push notifications? if you are usinf `FCM` plugin place this file in root directory. and if you are using `phonegap-push-plugin` than place it inside your `platform/app/src/debug` folder. if debug folder not exists make one.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying this file into: \platforms\android

There is a known issue when this file on certain versions of Android Studio gets corrupted etc. So just double check that the file is always there if you see this again.

If you are on never version of Android studio:

google-services.json needs to be in app/google-services.json. Then your config.xml needs to have:

```
<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
```